# Authentication URL in Java

Tags: java, html, servlet-filters, netbeans-8, servlet-3.0

I have a hotel reservation web application that when filling out a form should allow the user to move towards another `form`. But only if the first form is complete. What I want is to prevent someone from putting the address of the second form in the browser by skipping the first form.

The form has two buttons:

```
<input class="estilo" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()" value="Obtener Precio" >
<input class="estilo" type="submit"  value="Redireccion" >
```

The first based on the completed shows the price, the second should redirect to another `form` in case the first one is completed.

Comment: Please ask your questions in English.

Comment: Sorry . I confuse of page.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that, In the get method of second `form` you can check if first form is completed or not (you can check it by `setAttribute()` in POST method of first form and `getAttribute()` in Get method of second `form`.
Like ,

In the POST method of jsp having first form

```
request.setAttribute("firstform","yes");
```

then call jsp having second form

In the GET method of jsp having second form

```
if(request.getAttribute("firstForm")!=null && request.getAttribute("firstForm").equals("yes"){
{
      // redirect to jsp having second form
}
else{
      // get back to jsp having first form
}
```

In this case, whenever a user fills first form then only user can access second form. Otherwise user is redirected to jsp having first form.

Comment: But, How can i `getParameter()` from the first `form` if i am in the page of second `form` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Still can get the page through the borwser.

Comment: I have one Servlet that receives from the form.  I dont need to use two Servlet. I just want to avoid to someone get the page writing in the browser.

Comment: Okay. Just one thing you need to do, there will be one `GET` method for second `form` in that servlet which will be executed before displaying second `form`. In that `GET` method, you just need to check if first form is submitted or not. If first form is not submitted then redirect to first form. (I assume both forms are in different pages)